# After using keyboard.press_and_release(" ") the keyboard.get_hotkey_name(" ") doesn't work's in python

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

It enters if statement body and prints value1 as expected
but  `keyboard.press_and_release("h")`
doesn't work

```
import keyboard
import time

while 1: 
    value1 = keyboard.get_hotkey_name() 
    if value1 == "alt+x":     
        keyboard.press_and_release("h")
        print(value1)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I was expecting to get a particular hotkey and press another hotkey key or button